# Mellin transform of Gumbel distribution

Tags: integration, transformation, integral-transforms, mellin-transform

The probability density function (PDF) of Gumbel distribution is given as:

$$f\left(x\right)=\frac{\exp \left(-\left(\exp \left(-\frac{x-\mu}{\beta }\right)+\frac{x-\mu}{\beta }\right)\right)}{\beta },$$

where $\beta>0$. I would like to assume the translation $\mu$ to be $0$, which gives:

$$f\left(x\right)=\frac{\exp \left(-\left(\exp \left(-\frac{x}{\beta }\right)+\frac{x}{\beta }\right)\right)}{\beta }.$$

The Mellin transform of the PDF is therefore:

$$\int_0^{\infty } \frac{x^{s-1} \exp \left(-\left(\exp \left(-\frac{x}{\beta }\right)+\frac{x}{\beta }\right)\right)}{\beta } \ dx,$$
where $s>0$.

To solve this, I input the expression into Mathematica but no luck. Is there any other way to solve this?

Comment: i might be wrong but this could be a candidat for ramanujans master theorem...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a start,
I would do

$\begin{array}\\
\int_0^{\infty } \frac{x^{s-1} \exp \left(-\left(\exp \left(-\frac{x}{\beta }\right)+\frac{x}{\beta }\right)\right)}{\beta } \ dx
&=\int_0^{\infty } \frac{x^{s-1}\exp(-\frac{x}{\beta }) \exp \left(-\left(\exp \left(-\frac{x}{\beta }\right)\right)\right)}{\beta } \ dx\\
\text{Letting } y =\exp(-\frac{x}{\beta }), dy=-\frac1{\beta}\exp(-\frac{x}{\beta })dx,
&x=\beta\ln(1/y)\\
&=\int_1^{0 } -(\beta\ln(1/y))^{s-1} \exp (-y)\ dy\\
&=\beta^{s-1}\int_0^1 (\ln(1/y))^{s-1} \exp (-y)\ dy\\
\end{array}
$

This resembles the formula
for the
$s$-th derivative
of $\Gamma(x)$
at $x=1$.

Further than that
I know not.

Comment: I don't think you can say much more than this - except perhaps an elaboration of the fact that it is coming from the lower incomplete gamma function.

Comment: than you very much for the contribution @martycohen